# Video performance under a virtualized OS

Tags: virtualization

I'm going to be building a rather powerful desktop computer in the coming months, and I'm toying with the question about how smooth of a gaming experience I might have if I were to virtualize my OS. I've read a few similar questions and answers on other sites like tomshardware, but the people asking the questions seem to either leave out specific details about hardware, or the answers assume low hardware.

To keep the question short, I'd like to know if there is much (I do expect some) inherent inefficiencies in gaming under a virtualized OS, assuming I have sufficient hardware resources to dedicate to the virtual machine? Say I have 32GB of ram and I give 16GB to just the gaming OS, and I am not running any CPU intensive processes in other machines, will there be a sizable performance penalty on the gaming side just because of the hypervisor layer between the gaming OS and the hardware? How is 3d video performance in virtualized environments (again assuming adequate CPU and RAM resources allocated)? **I don't anticipate playing anything super taxing like Titanfall (or anything even remotely equivalent in video requirements) but I wouldn't mind the capability of playing something more than the quality that WoW and SC2/D3 puts out should I feel the urge.**

As for why I want to do this? I'm just asking "what if" at this point. I'm curious if it's even feasible; and if it is, I may find a benefit in doing this, because I want to have a system that can run several virtual machines doing specialized tasks (I'm a network administrator and want to be able to run various OSs at once without rebooting). It would be nice to have a simple host OS that has nothing installed on it other than the bare minimum required to host guest OSs, and then run my production on top of that, and have other servers running as guests doing various things like DNS, DHCP, Web, etc...

Comment: @techie007 That question was asked 3 years ago. There's a strong possibility that this is more possible now due to advances in virtualization tech.

Comment: Then perhaps add a bounty to the existing question asking for newer/updated answers.   IMO you're asking a duplicate question, but being vague and hypothetical about it, making it almost impossible to answer effectively.   3D gaming in a virtualized environment sucks in general - still.  RemoteFx or alike might help, but hard to say without testing specifics.  My advise: Try it and come back with questions about actual problems you run into.  But hey, takes more than my vote to close. ;)